# C# Calling Salesforce Rest Api with custom header

Tags: c#, rest, salesforce

I am trying to insert a new contact in Salesforce using Rest Api but unfortunately getting 400 Bad request exception.While using Postman everything is perfect but via code it is throwing exception. Someone guide me plz where I am wrong.

```
        string new_Contact_url =         ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SalesForceBaseUrl"] + "sobjects/contact";           
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new_Contact_url);
        request.Method = "POST";            
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Access_Token");
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
           {
               { "LastName", "Nafees" },
               { "Email", "email "},
               { "Tools_User_ID__c", "login_id" }
           };

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string postData = js.Serialize(keyValues);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.Trim());

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();          
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);         
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();                       
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);           
        var resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var responseBody = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(resp);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody["access_token"].ToString()))
        {
            string id = responseBody["Id"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to intercept your not-working C#-request and compare it to the working postman-request.

Comment: Muhammad I'm running into this same issue.  How did you fix it?  I'm already using TLS1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce recently switched from supporting TLS1.0 to TLS1.2.

In your C# code can you add this:

```
using System.Net;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

The ServicePointManager part should be before you send the request.